# .split() a data attribute isn't working when it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `.split(" ")` a data attribute value but it returns empty:

```
var bulletcontent = jQuery(this).closest("div").find("p").attr('data-bcontent');

// split content into words
var words = jQuery(bulletcontent).text().split(" ");
```

Why isn't this working?

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43439o8o/1/).

Comment: Why you're using jQuery for string, just use `bulletcontent.split(' ')`

Comment: Why are you wrapping `bulletcontent` in `jQuery` ?

Comment: `jQuery("hello world")` will be selector that match tag hello with tag world inside.

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/43439o8o/3/)

Comment: bulletcontent is already a string value given your example. Just use `var words = bulletcontent.split(" ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the fiddle: [**https://jsfiddle.net/43439o8o/2/**](https://jsfiddle.net/43439o8o/2/)

You dont need to get the `.text()`, the `.attr()` already return his content:

```
var bulletcontent = jQuery(content).attr('data-bcontent');

// split content into words
var words = bulletcontent.split(" "); //Remove the .text() method
```

As you can see at the [.attr() method docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), you can use it to return or set the attribute value:

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
var words = bulletcontent.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".click", function() {
    // find the bullet content stored in p tag inside li
    var content = $(this).prev("p").attr('data-bcontent');//get the p attr
    alert(content)
    var words = content.split(' ')//split
    alert(words[0]);//alert first  value
    alert(words[1]);//alert second value
  });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/43439o8o/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly function split() on the string:

```
var words = bulletcontent.split(" ");
```

for example you can see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` is a Method of [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) in Javascipt so there's no need to use jQuery. just add `.split(' ')` right next to your variable(String).

`.split()` returns array of strings depends on how you want to plit the original string.

This should work for you.

```
     var words = bulletcontent.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var words = bulletcontent.split(" ");
```